# Writing tests for custom error pages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, error-handling, controller, http-error

I have implemented custom error pages in my Rails app for a variety of error codes like so:

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...

  [400, 401, 403, 404, 405, 406, 418, 422, 500, 503].each do |status|
    get "/#{status}", to: "application#render_error", status: status
  end 
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  # ...

  # Render an error status using JSON.
  def render_error(status=nil)
    # If there's no status, try and get it from the params, which will be the case with the error routes.
    status ||= params[:status]

    message = error_message(status)
    render json: { error: message }, status: status
  end

  def error_message(status):
    # Return a simple error message.
  end
end
```

This is working well so far, as not found errors are automatically rendered using the error routes I set up, and I can manually render errors using `render_error`.

I've tried to write tests for these but I can't figure out the correct (or any) way to do it. This is what I've tried so far:

```
class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "Default error route should return correct status code" do
    get "/418"
    assert_response 418
  end

  test "render_error should return correct status code" do
    render_error 418
    assert_response 418
  end
end
```

The first of these fails due to the test not being able to the test interpreting `/418` as an action for the `application` controller. The second fails due to the test not being able to find the `render_error` method.

How should I write tests to test these properly?

Answer (score 0):

Functional tests like you are using here are used for [testing the actions within a particular controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers). Since these actions aren't specifically defined in your ApplicationController, you are running into problems.

You could rewrite these tests as [integration tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) (saved in test/integration/ folder), like so:

```
class ErrorsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "Default error route should return correct status code" do
    get "/418"
    assert_response 418
  end

end
```

This is a bit non standard, since integration tests are normally for testing the interaction of several controllers.. i.e the flow of your application.

Personally I much prefer [Rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) and would write these as [request specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec).

Comment: It looks like an integration test will do the job (I'll look into using RSpec); however I'm getting `undefined method \`render_error'` for the second one; how can I make `render_error` visible to the test?

Comment: Why do you need to test the render_error method here, if your route definition will pass the error status code to that method? You are already testing the correct response...

Comment: I want to test that when I pass a custom error code to the method that it renders the correct response.